# Splitting and aligning equation (long on both sides)

Tags: align, split

I would like to split and align an equation which is really long on both sides.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    & 2\sin(x - w)\sin(y - z) + 2\sin(y - w)\sin(z - x) + 2\sin(z - w)\sin(x - y)\\
\begin{split}
    ={} & \cos(x + z - y - w) - \cos(x + y - z - w) + \cos (x + y - z - w) - \cos(y + z - x - w)\\
    & + \cos(y + z - x - w) - \cos(x + z - y - w)
\end{split}\\
    ={} & 0 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

When I run the code, I get the following output.
[image]

The problem is that I want the '2' to align with the rest of the '='s. I also want the '+' in the third line to stay how it is right now (i.e. not aligned with the rest of the '='s.) How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

With use of instruction `\MoveEqLeft` and environment `\multlined`, defined in the `mathtools` package macro's you can write your equations as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \MoveEqLeft
2\sin(x - w)\sin(y - z) + 2\sin(y - w)\sin(z - x) + 2\sin(z - w)\sin(x - y)\\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
          \cos(x + z - y - w) - \cos(x + y - z - w) + \cos (x + y - z - w)\\ 
        - \cos(y + z - x - w) + \cos(y + z - x - w) - \cos(x + z - y - w) 
        \end{multlined} \\
    & = 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling with this for too long :(

Comment: @radiuszero, you are welcome! Happy TeX-ing!